# Apps got weird names and icons -> virus?

Tags: applications, security, samsung-galaxy-s-5, bugs

So, for instance one of apps renamed itself to "Content on this profile might be inappropriate for those under a certain age" and displays that message (and "Stopped.") in a MessageBox when started. Its icon also changed (to a grey heart; another changed to a grey edit-pencil). It works again after reinstalling it though. And my VLC player app is now called "_".

Do you think my phone fell victim to a virus? I got the Kaspersky virus scanner installed and when doing a full scan it finds nothing. I guess it's probably just some bug.

Maybe someone else had the same problem?

Edit: it appears that moving apps from my phone to the SD card was causing the icon-problem. The icon of Firefox changed to some grey icon after doing so. It changed back to the proper icon after I restarted the device. Not sure if that was also causing the app-names problem and I think it's unlikely to have caused that soundcloud-app-problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced the same issue myself but it definitely sounds like something caused by third party app(s).

What I would suggest is to boot your phone up in safe mode and systematically go through your apps, uninstall and install them until you have identified the offending app.

Example:

```
1. boot into safe mode
2. remove app1
3. boot up normally
4. check if resolved
5. if not, reinstall app1
6. repeat process for app2
```

If you have an approximate idea of when this happened, refer to your app installation history so you don't have to do this for all your installed apps and save some time!

Comment: How could the OP identify the offending app, if all of third-party apps cannot run at boot in safe mode?

Comment: My suggestion does not require third party apps to run, in fact, I suggested the safe boot method to force this situation.

Comment: *If* the offending app may not run in safe mode, *how* could OP identify it?

Comment: I would kindly refer you to the example steps I have included in my answer. If it's still unclear and OP doesn't understand, I'll happily edit my answer.